# What's the best way to store a computed column that maintains a sorting index in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sorting

So let's say I've got a table called `[transactions]` with an identity column as the primary key, a date field, and some other columns. I want to include a persistent column that is computed or somehow calculated which will effectively store the "sort order." This cannot simply be the ID column, however, because I'm sorting by date, and sometimes you might add a value retroactively.

So for example, if the table started out looking like this:

```
+-----+------------+---------+--------+--------+
| id  |    date    | account | amount | (sort) |
+-----+------------+---------+--------+--------+
|   1 | 2014-05-22 |      7  | 100.00 |    1   |
|   2 | 2014-05-29 |      7  |  45.25 |    2   |
|   3 | 2014-06-03 |      8  |  99.00 |    3   |
+-----+------------+---------+--------+--------+
```

Then, if I ran this statement:

```
INSERT INTO [transactions] ([date], [account], [amount]) 
VALUES ('2014-05-27', 8, 88.50);
```

I would want the sort column to be smart enough so that the table would then look like this:

```
+-----+------------+---------+--------+--------+
| id  |    date    | account | amount | (sort) |
+-----+------------+---------+--------+--------+
|   1 | 2014-05-22 |      7  | 100.00 |    1   |
|   2 | 2014-05-29 |      7  |  45.25 |    3   |
|   3 | 2014-06-03 |      8  |  99.00 |    4   |
|   4 | 2014-05-27 |      8  |  88.50 |    2   |
+-----+------------+---------+--------+--------+
```

Ideally, I'd like this column to persist as an actual column. What's the best way to accomplish this?

Comment: What is the purpose of storing this column? How are you planning on using it? If it is to be physically stored you would need to maintain it with triggers anyway as persisted computed columns won't do this but it can be calculated with `row_number` at runtime without storing it.

Comment: Is `sort` intended to just keep sort order or is it intended to be a row count?  If the former, there may be some other ways to store the information that are easier to maintain.

Comment: For easier pagination with large data sets. IMO MySQL's `LIMIT` clause handles pagination infinitely better than SQL Server's `ROW_NUMBER()` and attendant subqueries. Plus - think about it - if I were to create a nonclustered index on the `[date]` column, then this "sort" number is already being calculated *somewhere*, as a part of that index. I was just hoping there would be an easy way to access it.

Comment: @soapergem No it isn't stored as part of the NCI. The index just contains the key columns (plus included cols and row locator in leaf) it doesn't contain any sequential ordering number as you describe. It isn't needed in a Btree structure and would be inefficient to maintain there as well for the same reason as described in Gordon's answer. A single row data modification at the end could cause every row to require renumbering.

Comment: If you need it for pagination and have an index on the ordering column a simple row_number query should generally work fine. It can sometimes get inefficient for later pages and need a more complicated approach (especially if the index is not covering) but how often do users actually go beyond the first few pages?

Comment: I meant "pagination" only in the sense of breaking things into chunks; I wasn't implying that this was interactive for the user. In fact this application always covers the entire dataset; it just does so in batches, and the later queries tend to slow down significantly because `ROW_NUMBER()` takes forever to calculate.

Comment: Are you processing the chunks sequentially? If so just remember where you were up to and seek in from that point using the index on `date` (or `date,id` if date is not unique). `SELECT TOP(10) * FROM transactions Where date > @date ORDER BY date`

Comment: Yes, I am processing sequentially, and no, date is not unique. And what you just suggested sounds good (sounds like a potential answer!), but how do I do that? If my last row had an ID of `143798` and date `2013-10-02`, I can't just say `SELECT * FROM [transactions] WHERE [date] >= '2013-10-02' AND [id] > 143798`, because -- perhaps -- 143798 was a recent entry added retroactively, and in fact all the other October dates have IDs more in the range 100500 or so. Does that make sense?

Comment: If date is not unique then the clustered index key gets added in as a hidden key column to that non clustered index. Is the clustered index id? In fact can you supply the `create table` including indexes?

Comment: What's your distribution of data?  Could you just process day-at-a-time?  If these transactions are for a retail environment (I find it unlikely a single source will be generating enough transactions for `ROW_NUMBER()` to be a problem), do you have a `customerId` you could use instead?  As an aside, doesn't SQL Server support materialized views?  Would storing the data that way (also) be an option?

Answer (score 3):

You can just calculate the value when you need it:

```
select t.*, row_number() over (order by [date]) as [sort]
from transactions t;
```

Alternatively, just use `[date]` for `order by`.  I don't see why another column is necessary.

EDIT:

If you want to keep the column `sort` in order, then you are going to need a trigger.  And, the trigger will not be cheap.  The logic in the trigger would be essentially:

```
update transactions
    set sort = sort + 1
    where [date] > NEWDATE;

insert into transactions( . . . , [sort])
    select . . . , coalesce(max([sort])) + 1
    from transactions
    where [date] < NEWDATE;
```

(I'm leaving out all the stuff involved with defining a trigger.)

Although the `insert` can be made quite efficient with an index, this does affect the performance of the `update`, which has to affect every row with a larger date.  If you are almost always inserting rows with a newer date, this might be a reasonable trade-off.

Comment: One possible use case for another column would be to index it and seek into rows 1000000 to 1000010 efficiently perhaps.

Comment: @MartinSmith . . . The irony is that the savings on the `select` come at the expense of much more work on each `insert`/`delete`.  That is a reasonable price to pay in certain scenarios.

Comment: Indeed, if a single row is inserted earlier then the min one so far then all rows in the table get an update! Would be good to know why the OP (thinks they) need this.

Comment: Martin Smith hit the nail on the head with his first comment.